# Ubuntu 16.04 - Wi-fi , IP is on a network different than my gateway

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, internet, iptables, gateway

I have a partitioned Lenovo pc. One partition with Ubuntu desktop 16.04, one with Windows 10.
Windows has internet connection, Ubuntu does not. It is on a different network.

I tried gathering some info:

[cat syslog grep dhclient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o78wp.png)

[dmesg grep iflwifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXGx6.png)

[etc network interfaces , route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86gSU.png)

[ifconfig -a , iwconfig , ping gw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik7Ni.png)

Worked fine until about a week ago. I cannot figure out what I did wrong, nor why I am not on the same network as my router/gateway (10.0.0.x).

And why I cannot change it via cmd.

Tried:

dhclient -r

route del default

route add default gw myrouterip

iptables -F

service networking stop/reload/start/restart

I believe I've mostly used NetworkManager to connect so far.
I've tried playing around with /etc/network/interfaces to solve this, without much success (you can see an empty "#net interface" on one of the pics).

Can anybody help me figure this out?

[Output cat syslog grep etwork tail20.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18rkM.png)

Comment: The IP address 169.254.x.y simply means that the router was asked for an IP address and it failed. In short, you simply failed to connect. Is the password triple checked as correct? Any clues here? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork | tail -n 20`

Comment: What kind of router do you have? Is this a corporate network or a home network?

Comment: Password triple checked as correct? -> What did you mean? I cannot see any of the various wi-fi networks/SSIDs that should be available. 
I cannot click on any network to be prompted for a pw. 

I'll now post the result of the command you asked me for. I'll edit my main post


My router: ZyXEL VMGxxxx-xxxx. This is my home network. My phone and windows box communicate and connect perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to figure it out, feeling pretty dumb.

```
nmcli device
```

gave as result: wlp2s0 Unmanaged.

Either:

```
sudo nmcli device set wlp2s0 managed yes
sudo nmcli device set wlp2s0 managed on
sudo nmcli device set wlp2s0 managed true
```

I don't know which one did the trick, but it works now.